# Realm Migration Issues

Tags: android, realm

I have an issue with getting Realm to migrate successfully and could do with a little help having been tinkering with it for a couple of weeks now..

I have a realm db working by which I mean saving data and and returning data.

Lets say I want to add a new field "username". I update my RealmObject code to utilise the new field. In my App.java I then use:

```
   System.out.println("Configuring Realm...");
   RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
   realm = Realm.getInstance(config1);
   realm.close();
```

My Migration.java looks like:

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        RealmObjectSchema theSchema = schema.get("RealmStore");
        System.out.println("Realm version is " + oldVersion);
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            theSchema
                    .addField("username", String.class);
            oldVersion++;
            System.out.println("Realm migrated from 0 to 1");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the app and the following output is given:

```
I/System.out: Configuring Realm...
I/System.out: Realm version is 0
I/System.out: Realm migrated from 0 to 1
```

All good! Except..! When you re-run the app, you now get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rh.realmy/com.rh.realmy.Main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Realm on disk is newer than the one specified: v1 vs. v0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It happens when you use a config without specific `schemaVersion` or a lower `schemaVersion` than the version after migration. Do you open Realm with a different configuration?

Comment: Hi beeender, no, no other configuration

Comment: That is really strange ... do you mind to share your project privately? To help@realm.io

Comment: Yes no problem will send as soon as I'm with my laptop in a few hours. Thanks

Comment: and also the old db for us to reproduce the problem :)

Comment: Email sent beeender :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in other parts of the code you are calling `Realm.getInstance(context)`.

This is equivalent to doing the following:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).schemaVersion(0).build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Which will give you the schema mismatch error you are seeing.

You can read more about default configurations here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#the-default-realm

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

Kohi:

This is the code I used in the end (which works)...

In my App.java:

```
private Realm realm;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Setup Realm
    RealmConfiguration config1 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(config1); // Automatically run migration if needed
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1);
    realm.close();
    }
}
```

In my class that uses realm:

```
private Realm realm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Open the default Realm for the UI thread.
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}
```

Then use realm as needed

Hope this helps